# iphone code - using NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i implement an NSArray in this method (instead of just defining each one of the objects).

code:

```
- (void) fadeOutShuffleAnimation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    juw1.alpha = 0.0;
    juw2.alpha = 0.0;
    juw3.alpha = 0.0;
    juw4.alpha = 0.0;
    ...
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if juw* are uiviews (or uiview subclasses) you can assign them unique tag property and loop through them like:

```
for (loop tag condition){
   [parentView viewWithTag: tag].alpha = 0;
}
```

So actually after you create your items and add to parentView as subviews you might not need to store items as you can always get them using their tags.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take all objects from view.subviews and set alpha to 0

example:

```
for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
   if([v isKindOfObject:[UIImageView class]] ) {
      v.alpha = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// initialize _juwArray array
NSMutableArray *_juwArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    // instantiate _juw instance and add it to _juwArray
    // assuming conformation to NSCopying/NSMutableCopying protocols
    // or that Juw is a subclass of UIView  
    [_juwArray addObject:_juw];
}

// set alpha values
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    [((Juw *)[_juwArray objectAtIndex:index]) setAlpha:0.0];
}
```